# My App Crashes in MainActivity

Tags: android

Someone please help me. My app crashes and I don't know why. My code is as follows:

```
package com.thenexttech.formula;

import.android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {




Button ourButton;
    TextView theTextView;
    EditText why2;
    EditText why1;
    EditText ex2;
    EditText ex1;
    int iny2;
    int iny1;
    int inx2;
    int inx1;




@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ourButton.setOnClickListener(new OurOnClickListener(this));



theTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        why2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y2);
        why1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y1);
        ex2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x2);
        ex1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x1);


int iny2 = Integer.valueOf(why2.getText().toString());
        int iny1 = Integer.valueOf(why1.getText().toString());


int inx2 = Integer.valueOf(ex2.getText().toString());



int inx1 = Integer.valueOf(ex1.getText().toString());




}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.




getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.



int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

If you need to see more code, just ask. By the way, I am a beginning Android developer. I need to add more details to my post so um, my name is Christopher, I like food, life is pretty good, yeah.

Comment: Hi Christopher and welcome to SO. Please post the stacktrace of the exception, this will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Egor what's the stacktrace?

Comment: Please google it, it will be quite helpful to know what's "logcat" and what's a "stack trace"

Comment: @StealthDroid Post your logs from logcat

Comment: Post your logcat but it definitely seems like a case of you trying to cast a blank string into an integer. Since your editexts may not have content in the beginning.

Comment: very unpleasant variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is on these lines:

```
    int iny2 = Integer.valueOf(why2.getText().toString());
    int iny1 = Integer.valueOf(why1.getText().toString());
    int inx2 = Integer.valueOf(ex2.getText().toString());
    int inx1 = Integer.valueOf(ex1.getText().toString());
```

I suppose that the these TextView are empty on the beginning Try change the lines above to lines below:

```
    iny2 = why2.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(why2.getText().toString());
    iny1 = why1.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(why1.getText().toString());
    inx2 = ex2.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(ex2.getText().toString());
    inx1 = ex1.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(ex1.getText().toString());
```

If you want to do sth with this values when you click on your button you have to use lines above inside of onClick method from OnClickListener as is shown in the code below:

```
    ourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iny2 = why2.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(why2.getText().toString());
            iny1 = why1.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(why1.getText().toString());
            inx2 = ex2.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(ex2.getText().toString());
            inx1 = ex1.length() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(ex1.getText().toString());
          //Do something with these

        }
    });
```